# Laravel Not Encrypting Cookies

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am facing an issue where Laravel is not encrypting a Cookie that I am setting in a middleware. Due to this, when I try to retrieve the cookie value in another controller its value is coming blank. Below is my Middleware code

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
if($request->hasCookie('uuid'))
{
    return $next($request);
}
else
{
    $uuid = Uuid::generate();
    if (Auth::check())
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    else
        $user_id = '';

    Visitors::create([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'uuid' => $uuid
    ]);

    $response = $next($request);
    return $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('uuid', $uuid));
}
}
```

I have created a UUID middleware to set a UUID parameter anytime someone comes to the site. I am using this middleware in my routes.

This is causing the UUID cookie to be set but it is not encrypted.

In another controller function, when I try to retrieve the value of the uuid cookie using

```
$uuid = Request::Cookie(uuid);
```

it is coming out blank.

(Note that I am using 2 middlewares for my route ('uuid', 'web'). If I change the sequence of middleware in my routes to ('web', 'uuid'), I start getting TokenExceptionError.)

Anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: How do you know the cookie is not being encrypted? It sounds more like it's not being set at all.

Comment: Does your session cookie get encrypted?

Comment: @Kryten: I can see the UUID cookie. It is in the regular UUID format and not encrypted.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Yes the session cookie does get encrypted.

Comment: And how do you register the middleware and apply it to your route? It seems this middleware is run before middleware that encrypts cookies

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo I have a route group like Route::group(['middleware' => ['uuid', 'web']], function () {}. The problem is that if I have web before uuid, the uuid cookie does get encrypted. However I get a TokenAuthentication error on login. The login breaks if I switch web with uuid and vice versa

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo Also i have registered the middleware in my kernel.php like protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'uuid' => \App\Http\Middleware\UuidMiddleware::class,
    ];

Answer (score 0):

It seems your **uuid** middleware is run before middleware that encrypts cookies. Middleware for your route group is defined as **['uuid', 'web']** and middleware that encrypts/decrypts cookies is in **web** group.

Add your middleware at the end of **web** group or change the order of middlewares in your route group to **['web', 'uuid']**.